# Python TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable despite proper assignment

Tags: python, methods, int, typeerror

When I run this program, it gives me a type error when it reaches the display_pipe method because it does not think that one of the variables is an int, when every single parameter is entered as an int, and all other variables in the method are integers.

```
'''This is a simple replica of flappy bird for the pc that I made to help me
understand python.'''


import random
import pygame
from pygame import *
import math
import sys

#Presets for window
size=width,height=500,500
Ag=-9.80665
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
white=(255,255,255)
blue=(0,0,255)
red=(255,0,0)
gray_bgColor=(190,193,212)

#Initialise pygame Surface as screen
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
#Creates icon for window
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Flappy Bird Replica")
icon = pygame.image.load("images/icon.png").convert()
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

class graphics():
    #Holds the methods for loading/displaying graphics
    def load_images(self):
        #Loads the background and sprite images
        self.background_image=pygame.image.load("images/flappy_background.png").convert()
        self.bird_image=pygame.image.load("images/flappy_sprite.jpg").convert()
        self.pipe_image=pygame.image.load("images/flappy_pipe.png").convert()
        self.pipe_image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.inverted_pipe_image=pygame.transform.flip(self.pipe_image,False,True)
        self.bird_image.set_colorkey(white)

    def display_pipe(self,pipe_xPos,pipe_height):
        #Calculates new position of pipe
        pipe_yPos=318
        pipe_vX=-1
        inverted_pipe_yPos=0
        #Checks if there is a pre-existing velocity and xPosition
        #and assigns defaults
        if pipe_xPos==None or pipe_xPos<=-78:
            pipe_xPos=500
            pipe_height=random.randrange(0,3)
        pipe_xPos+=pipe_vX
        #Randomizes the height of the pipes
        if pipe_height==0:
            self.inverted_pipe_image=pygame.transform.scale(self.inverted_pipe_image,(self.inverted_pipe_image.get_width(),200))
        elif pipe_height==1:
            self.inverted_pipe_image=pygame.transform.scale(self.inverted_pipe_image,(self.inverted_pipe_image.get_width(),150))
        elif pipe_height==2:
            self.inverted_pipe_image=pygame.transform.scale(self.inverted_pipe_image,(self.inverted_pipe_image.get_width(),100))

        screen.blit(self.pipe_image,[pipe_xPos,pipe_yPos])
        screen.blit(self.inverted_pipe_image,[pipe_xPos,0])

        return pipe_height

    def display_loop(self,bird_vY,bird_yPos,pipe_xPos,pipe_height):
        #Calculates new position of bird
        bird_xPos=200
        jumpspeed=-1.7
        fallspeed=0.02
        #Checks if there is a pre-existing velocity and yPosition
        #and assigns defaults
        if bird_vY==None or bird_yPos==None:
            bird_vy=0
            bird_yPos=200
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                    bird_vY=jumpspeed
        bird_vY+=fallspeed
        bird_yPos+=bird_vY

        #Blits all the images to the screen
        screen.blit(self.background_image,[0,0])
        screen.blit(self.bird_image,[bird_xPos,bird_yPos])

        pipe_xPos,pipe_height=self.display_pipe(pipe_xPos,pipe_height)

        pygame.display.flip()

        return bird_vY,bird_yPos,pipe_xPos,pipe_height

class titleScreen():
    #Holds the methods for the title screen/menu
    def title(self):
        #Different fonts
        titleFont=pygame.font.SysFont("verdana",30,bold=True,italic=True)
        startFont=pygame.font.SysFont("verdana",25,bold=False,italic=False)
        quitFont=pygame.font.SysFont("verdana",25,bold=False,italic=False)
        #Sets up the title
        titleText="Flappy Game"
        titlePos=(0,0)
        renderTitle=titleFont.render(titleText,1,blue,gray_bgColor)
        titlex,titley=titleFont.size(titleText)
        screen.blit(renderTitle,titlePos)
        #Sets up the start button
        startText="Start Game"
        startPos=(0,titley)
        renderStart=startFont.render(startText,1,blue,gray_bgColor)
        startx,starty=startFont.size(startText)
        self.start_rect = pygame.Rect(startPos[0],titley,startx,starty)
        screen.blit(renderStart,startPos)
        #Sets up the quit button
        quitText="Quit"
        quitPos=(0,starty+titley)
        renderQuit=quitFont.render(quitText,1,red,gray_bgColor)
        quitx,quity=quitFont.size(quitText)
        self.quit_rect = pygame.Rect(quitPos[0],titley+starty,quitx,quity)
        screen.blit(renderQuit,quitPos)

    def get_click(self):
        #Gets mouse click and processes outcomes
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                x,y=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                #Tests for start:
                if self.start_rect.collidepoint(x,y):
                    print("start")
                    return True
                elif self.quit_rect.collidepoint(x,y):
                    print("quit")
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    return False

#Assign objects to respective classes        
titleC=titleScreen()
graphicsC=graphics()

def showTitle():
    #bundles all title_screen functions
    screen.blit(graphicsC.background_image,[0,0])
    titleC.title()
    pygame.display.flip()

def main():
    graphicsC.load_images()
    while True:
        title=True
        while title==True:
            showTitle()
            start=titleC.get_click()
            if start==True:
                title=False
                bird_yPos=200
                bird_vY=0
                pipe_xPos=500
                pipe_height=1
        while title==False:
            bird_vY,bird_yPos,pipe_xPos,pipe_height=graphicsC.display_loop(bird_vY,bird_yPos,pipe_xPos,pipe_height)
            pygame.time.delay(3)
            if bird_yPos>=height-120:
                title=True            
main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Klaus\Documents\coding\python stuff\pygames\Flappy Python\flappy_bird_source.py", line 162, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Klaus\Documents\coding\python stuff\pygames\Flappy Python\flappy_bird_source.py", line 158, in main
    bird_vY,bird_yPos,pipe_xPos,pipe_height=graphicsC.display_loop(bird_vY,bird_yPos,pipe_xPos,pipe_height)
  File "C:\Users\Klaus\Documents\coding\python stuff\pygames\Flappy Python\flappy_bird_source.py", line 85, in display_loop
    pipe_xPos,pipe_height=self.display_pipe(pipe_xPos,pipe_height)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please give us the *full traceback* of the exception.

Comment: Added it at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display_pipe()` returns an integer.

You are trying to assign `pipe_xPos,pipe_height` to the return value, as if it is a tuple with two elements.

If you want to return the values of `pipe_xPos` and `pipe_height` from `display_pipe()`, then change your return line to:

```
return pipe_xPos, pipe_height
```

Comment: So does that mean that the method can only return one value?

Comment: @AndrewLalis No, it can return as many as you want, but you need to tell it to do that.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to fix it.